Multiples of 3 or 5 Can this be done using else if statements?
I've tried the following code and it works fine except for 0 or negative numbers, it says:
"cannot access local variable 'add_list' where it is not associated with a value".
I've seen how this can be done other ways I'm just wondering if it can be done using an elif statement. I've tried "break", indentation and different orders but get the same error.
def solution(number):
    raw_list = range(number)
    my_list = []
    for num in raw_list:
        if num < 0:
            my_list.append(0)
            return my_list 
        elif num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
            my_list.append(num)
            add_list = sum(my_list)
    return add_list


If the range doesn't contain any multiples of 3 or 5, you never assign add_list. Move that assignment out of the loop, you don't need to calculate the sum until the very end.

Also, are you confident that the intended solution is to return a list sometimes but a number at other times? That's a somewhat unusual structure.

range(number) will never contain a number less than 0, so the first if can never succeed.

Why do you some times returns list ([0]) but otherwise return an integer?

"Can this be done" - Can what be done? You forgot to tell us what the code is supposed to do.

If the range doesn't contain any multiples of 3 or 5, you never execute add_list = sum(my_list). As a result, you get an error when you try to return it.
There's no need to calculate the sum each time through the loop, since you're overwriting the sum from the previous iteration. Take that out of the loop, then it won't be dependent on the elif condition.
def solution(number):
    raw_list = range(number)
    my_list = []
    for num in raw_list:
        if num < 0:
            my_list.append(0)
            return my_list 
        elif num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0:
            my_list.append(num)
    add_list = sum(my_list)
    return add_list

Since the if condition can never be true, you could also leave that out. Then you can simplify the whole thing to:
def solution(number):
    return sum(num in range(number) if num % 3 == 0 or num % 5 == 0)

BTW, raw_list is a poor name for the variable. range() doesn't return a list, it returns a range object that acts as an generator.

the range function does not take 0 because usually the range start at 0 until the given number.so negative numbers don't work.for fixing the "cannot access local variable 'add_list' where it is not associated with a value" error you just have to keep the add_list variable outside of the for loop therefore the operation happens after the values are appended to my_list.
